# Explain solid angle $\Omega=\int\int_S \frac{\bar r \cdot \hat n dS}{r^3}=\int\int_S \sin(\theta) d\theta d\varphi$

Tags: geometry, solid-angle

I am trying to understand this formula from Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle). It is a generalization of radian. I am trying to do unit check but I cannot see how the units match. Steradion must be dimensioless unit (derived SI unit).

This $\int\int_S \frac{\bar r \cdot \hat n dS}{r^3}$ has area times a small area in the numerator and volume in denomirator so integral of one divided by meter. I am doing somewhere an idea-mistake. Where?

**Formula from Wikipedia about solid angle**

> [image]

Comment: The units work out fine! In your last expression using $\theta, \phi$, well, radians are unitless (they're just ratops) as is $\sin \theta$ (which is also just a ratio). Same goes for the first formula -- the dot product leaves a unit in "meters" (for instance) while dS is measured in "meters^2". The reason is that $\vec r$ is a distance vector (meters) while $n$ is a unit vector (with no units). Dividing by the $r^3$ (meters cubed) gives something unitless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of solid angle as the fraction of a total unit sphere surface area ($4 \pi$) that a cap of the sphere is.  The analogy is a fraction of the circumference of a circle that an arc of that circle is, is a circular angle.

Also note that $dS = r^2 \sin{\theta} d \theta d\phi$, and that $\hat{r} . \hat{n} = 1$ for the sphere.

Comment: Of course, thank you! +1 for the last notice, I had hard time to think the dot product there. For future random walkers, you can find the general case for the area of sphere [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17850/how-to-deduce-the-area-of-sphere-in-polar-coordinates) with rigorous Jacobian calculations. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Each vector has its magnitude & direction then we have
$$\bar r=|r|\hat r=r\hat r$$
Since, the unit radial vector $\hat r$ & the unit normal vector $\hat n$ to the spherical surface are in the same direction i.e. the angle between these vectors  $\alpha=0^{o} \space$ hence we have
$$\hat r \cdot \hat n=|\hat r| \cdot |\hat n|cos \alpha=1 \cdot 1 cos0^{o}=1$$
And an elementary area $dS$ on the spherical surface with a radius $r\space$ is given as
$$dS=(rd \theta)\cdot(rsin\theta d\phi)=r^2sin\theta d\theta d\phi$$

Where, $\theta$ is angle of longitude & $\phi$ is angle of latitude
Now, substituting the corresponding values in left hand side of the expression we get the solid angle
$$=\iint_S\frac{\bar r\cdot \hat n \space dS}{r^3}=\iint_S\frac{r(\hat r\cdot \hat n) \space r^2sin\theta d\theta d\phi}{r^3}=\iint_S\frac{r^3(1)\space sin\theta d\theta d\phi}{r^3}=\iint_Ssin\theta d\theta d\phi$$

It is obvious that the solid angle is a dimensionless quantity having SI unit Ste-radian (sr).